How to validate gitlab access token in spring boot?
I'm getting gitlab private token in request param. How to validate this token valid or not.
I have used gitlab4j-api maven dependency but getting error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput
tried below code:
 @PostMapping("/validate-token")
    public void validateToken(@RequestParam String token, @RequestBody Object json) {
        System.out.printf("json " + json);
        System.out.println("Token " + token);


        //TODO need to fix error on below line.
        GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi("https://gitlab.com", token);


        System.out.println("gitLabApi " + gitLabApi.toString());
        UserApi userApi = gitLabApi.getUserApi();
        System.out.println("UserApi " + userApi);
        if (userApi != null) {
            System.out.println("token is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("token is not valid");
        }

    }

Error -> Stack Trace
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/gitlab4j/api/GitLabApiClient.createApiClient()Ljavax/ws/rs/client/Client; @18: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @18
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/gitlab4j/api/GitLabApiClient', 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder' }
    stack: { 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 7d59 b700 7e2a b400 1ab6 007f 4c2b
    0000010: 122d b600 8057 2b12 2fb6 0080 572a b400
    0000020: 8199 0013 2b2a b400 82b6 0083 2ab4 0084
    0000030: b600 8557 2a2b b600 86b5 0031 2ab4 0031
    0000040: b0                                     
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@52,Object[#374])
] with root cause

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/gitlab4j/api/GitLabApiClient.createApiClient()Ljavax/ws/rs/client/Client; @18: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @18
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/gitlab4j/api/GitLabApiClient', 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder' }
    stack: { 'org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:


Do you have:

javax.ws.rs
javax.ws.rs-api

in your pom.xml?
ClassNotFoundException's are usually due to dependency problems

@EthanConrad: Still getting error. I have added stack trace in question.

Errors are gone after fixing the dependency error, but validation is not working.

If I passed invalid token, then userApi  is not null, in all the cases always getting some some string value in userApi, Not understanding about GitlabApi working.
